# deployment of referencing DLLs in SharePoint

Tags: .net, sharepoint, deployment, reference, target

If we compile a .NET solution using VS 2010 that will run in a asp.net 2.0 environment and we reference an external DLL and plan to run deploy and run the solution in Sharepoint I understand I will need to deploy my DLL and create a safecontrol entry.  But what about the referenced DLL? Will I need PublicKeytoken an dsafecontrol entry for it?

```
<SafeControl Assembly="System.Web, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" TypeName="*" Safe="True" AllowRemoteDesigner="True" />
```

Also, do I need to set the target to 2.0 in visual studio 2010? Where/how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to deploy the referenced dll to the GAC as well.  Once it is in there you can get the PublicKeyToken.

Comment: what if my project already has a manifest file and creates the safecontrol entry.. it will know what to add it with? Also I'm doing this for the first time in vs 2010 it's complaining that my sharePoint.dll ref requires a later version of .net and I'm set to 2.0 and it's moss 2007 I'm deploying to. Also does any of this relate to the guid in my assemblyinfo.cs or the solutionID in my manifest file? thanks.

Comment: Is it even possible to compile/deploy to 2007 from vs 2010?

Comment: Just reading what it would take to build a webpart in vs2010 for moss and 2007 and probably not worth it for us. As a quick and dirty - is it possible for us to drop the DLLs in the bin folder of the web app and refernce them from codebehind in sharePoint pages so as not to have to install vs 2007? If so, would I need a safe control key entry?

Comment: I don't think so.  Every time I have accessed a third party assembly from anything SharePoint I had to register it in the GAC.  I'm not sure about the Safe control key entry.  I would try it without and if it squawks add it in.

Comment: sorry.. <@ Import .. not using on the directive. I have the simple code working in simple page with a reference from vs2010 outside of sharePoint. Identical code giving me An unexpected error has occurred.